# Wix: Determine if SqlLocalDB is installed

Tags: wix, localdb

I'm trying to determine is it LocalDb installed and i tried to go the way from this link  [Determine if SqlLocalDB is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486554/determine-if-sqllocaldb-is-installed)

But i've got an error on my log file that:  Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion'

My code is:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="SearchForLocalDB" 
               Root="HKLM"
               Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion"
               Value="CurrentVersion"
               Variable="LocalDBVersion" 
               Result="value"/>
<PackageGroup Id="LOCALDB">
  <MsiPackage  Id="LOCALDB"
              DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2014"
              Permanent="yes"
              Visible="yes"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              SourceFile=".\SqlLocalDB.msi"
              InstallCondition="(LocalDBVersion &lt;= &quot;12.0&quot;)"
    />
</PackageGroup>
```

Comment: Your linked post has Result="raw" not Result="value"

Comment: And don't forget you may need to specify Win64 if this 64-bit key.

Comment: There is no "raw" values for Result. Only "exists" and "value". And lol Win64 is really work. Omg so stupid. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Doesn't Wix automatically open the correct registry for 64/32 bit dependant on the installation type? If not then could you expand on what's required in "specifying a 64-bit key"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Result='exists'` rather than pulling the actual value. You already have the version in the key value so you don't need to check for it in the InstallCondition.